# Does sprinting in Fallout 4's Survival mode accelerate the rate at which I will become thirstier?

Tags: fallout-4

When I do not fear danger or have a long distance to travel I will sprint to reach the destination faster. Survival mode, to some extent, relates more to real life than the other modes, which makes me wonder if sprinting makes me thirstier faster than if I were to simply run to my destination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thirst does not accumulate faster under any circumstances such as sprinting. It is always a slow, gradual change.

[Source](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Thirst)

> Thirst accumulates slowly at all times.